# How to show some characters in data-toggle tooltip bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing issue with data-toggle title in which i have `&` character to display.

Here in title i also want `&` to be shown. It should be like `title="Allowed characters [._/&#:-$a-zA-Z0-9]"`.

If i remove `&`, it is working fine. If i add `&`, it is giving issue.

Can anyone please help me in getting the result.

Comment: Pass in html `&amp;` = &

Comment: Please share your HTML.

Comment: replace & charcters with &#38; in your html

Answer (score 3):

No it will work fine i think you might not be declaring it

this code work fine for me

```
  <div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
   <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Allowed characters [._/&#:- $a-zA-Z0-9]">Rule for Work</a>
  </div>


 // js

 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

> see jsfiddle here   **[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/m273oudr/)**